# How to add an ORM entity to a model

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

My application is growing in complexity, and I'm finding that going from ORM entities directly to the view is insufficient.

I want to add models. They will take the data from my ORM entities, but also add some functionality. For example, my `User` ORM entity has an `endDate` property and a `trial` property. I'd like to add an `isExpired` method that ensures

1. The `endDate` is later than today, and
2. `trial` is false

(This is a simple example. My requirements are much more complex, which is why I want to move the logic outside of the view.)

What is the correct way to do this? Say I make a `UserModel` class. Will the `User` object be a property on that class, in addition to my other properties/methods? Will I be able to preserve Doctrines ability to fetch all objects in a single query?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add the `isExpired()` method directly to the entity? No one forces you to keep just the DB stuff in the entities.

Comment: This won't mess up persistence, or anything like that?

Comment: There's also another wrinkle. I'm using [Native SQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) in this particular case, because I want to fetch related data for each object. So, there's already a 'wrapper class' (I think this is the only way to do it?). Could I bring the new props/methods from my entity along as well, to the wrapper class?

Comment: Elnur's suggestion won't mess up persistence at all, you're just processing the entity's data to form to generate a information function.  Should work with your wrapper as well, give parent calls or whatnot.  I use this technique quite a bit.

Comment: No, it won't mess up anything. You can write any method you want. All the ORM cares about is fields with its annotations on it.

Comment: And you don't need to use native SQL to fetch related data for each object. [Fetch JOINs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins) do that.